# need a typefont with caps that ascend and descend below baseline

Tags: font-recommendation

I know everyone rags on Papyrus, but I love that the caps are higher and lower than the lc letters (see The Paper Store logo).  I see this on script fonts as well (e.g. Typnic Script), but don't want script.  Larger caps are much easier for dyslexics to read, and it's great for a logo with multiple words.
So, other than Papyrus, which fonts do this?  I can't seem to find a way to search for this quality.
Thanks, Lydia

Comment: Is it an option to just manually set the lowercase letters' baseline higher?

Answer (score 2):

Papyrus isn't like that by default. The Paper Store logo was simply tweaked so it looked that way. Just as someone tweaked papyrus to do that, you could tweak any typeface to do the same.

Comment: Fair enough!  Given that this is a design site, I'm guessing you use a Mac.  With Windows Word and PowerPoint, all Papyrus caps show up both above and below the lc letters.  Our TMs, logos and subheads have a lot of As and Ws, and they are just gorgeous in Papyrus.  Trying to find a non-reviled alternative, as well as one that exists in the Squarespace universe of fonts.

Comment: @Lydia you are correct! It appears the versions of Papyrus that ship with Windows vs. OSX are different. I had never noticed that before.

Comment: FYI to anyone interested in the above search for a font with the features I mentioned initially:  We looked at hundreds of fonts with great As and Ws, but none other seemed to have the caps that ascend and descend beyond the lc letters.  So, we purchased Smooth Papyrus, which does not have the breaks in the letters, and is a bit less "old Egyptian" in feel.  It looks great and seems to work well in Squarespace.  -- Lydia